# Open .pdf files in new tab and not download - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a quick question, I have my javaScript code setup where it downloads any ".pdf" files that I have on my JavaScript table. How do I make it where it doesn't download the file, but instead opens it up in a new tab?

Here is the code:

JavaScript file: o365FileSlide.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
 
 if(current_title == 'Introduction to OneDrive')
  getOneDriveFiles();
});

function getOneDriveFiles(){
 //PnP call here

 $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/"
 });

 $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Shared Documents/OneDrive/").files.orderBy("Title").get().then(function(f){
  console.log(f);
  
  var files = '';
  
  $.each(f, function(index, value){
   var filesHtml = "<div class='file'>" + 
       "<a href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "'><img src='/O365Training/PublishingImages/wordThumbSmall.png' width='75px' height='75px' /></a>" + 
       "<a href='" + value.ServerRelativeUrl + "'><p id='fileTitle' margin-top: 10px>" + value.Title + "</p></a>" + 
       "</div>";
   
   files = files + filesHtml;
  });
  
  $(".files").append(files).window.open(files);
  
 });
}
```

```html
<div id="filesDiv" class="row" style="padding-left: 15px;">
    <div class="files" target="_blank"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/publiccdnlib/apps/O365-Slider/o365FileSlide.js"></script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBmcc.png

If anyone could give me some pointers, I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Please close thread, this has been resolved.

Comment: How do you solve this?

Comment: `Content-Disposition` setting may be the issue. Answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1277819/why-does-chrome-sometimes-download-a-pdf-instead-of-opening-it#1277820